# Electron with gkm module. After built gkm is not working

Tags: electron, node-modules, electron-packager

In development ENV, gkm module is worked great. It can track my keypress event. But, when I build the app. gkm is not worked. What should I do?  Here my code.

```
    <script>
    let count = 0;
    const electron = window.require('electron');
    const { ipcRenderer } = electron;
    const gkm = window.require('gkm');

     gkm.events.on('key.*', function(data) {
        console.log('listening global keyboard')
    });


    ipcRenderer.on('item:add', function (e, item) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        const itemText = document.createTextNode(item);
        li.appendChild(itemText);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    ipcRenderer.on('item:clear', function () {
        ul.innerHTML = ""
    });
</script>
```